# Sortable divs from/to draggable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have `.rc` divs inside a `.rcs` div. The `.rcs` divs are sortable. The `.rcs` divs are inside a `.ra` div. The `.ra` div are draggable.

When I move a `.rc` from the first `.ra` to the second one, during the transition, the `.rc` is hidden.

I don't get this behaviour when I make the `.ras` div sortable (`.ras` is the parent of `.ra`).

Thanks for help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ra").draggable({
    zIndex: 100
  });
  $(".rcs").sortable({
    connectWith: ".rcs",
  });
});
```

```css
.ra {
  background-color: white;
  width: 28%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 1%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 26%;
  position: absolute;
}

.rcs {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: : -50px;
  height: 150px;
}

.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: white;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="ras">
  <div class="ra">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="ra_name">Martini, Johnny </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rcs" id="ra1_rcs">
      <div class="box">titre</div>
      <div class="box">titre</div>
      <div class="box">titre</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ra">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="ra_name">Martin, John</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rcs">
      <div class="box">titre</div>
      <div class="box">titre</div>
      <div class="box">titre</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue comes from `CSS`. If you comment `overflow: auto;` from your `CSS` like below, it works properly.

```
.ra {
  background-color: white;
  width: 28%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 1%;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  position: relative;
}
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/4qk39ja4/14/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali !